# Validate Array of Objects Before Creating Any with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I have a Backend with Node-Mongoose. I have a Schema "Customer" with some fields (like Name and Avatar). I have a function to create a new Customer. Everything works fine. Now I need to create many customers, I do this by sending an array of objects as req.body instead of a sole object.

I am able to do it, but if any of the objects has a validation error (no valid email or name), it is NOT stored in the database. However, the ones that are allright, are indeed stored.

Problem is: I need to validate the whole array of objects before creating any document. If any of the objects is invalid, none of them should be created.

I have been searching but I can't find anything. Any help?

My original function is very simple:

```
exports.createCustomer = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const newCustomer = await Customer.create(req.body)
if (!newCustomer) return next(new AppError('The customer could not be created', 404))

res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
        newCustomer
    }
})
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write an example for how to solve your question，suppose want to verify the email address's length  is correct.

```
//schema

const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'email must input'],
    minlength: [5, 'min length'],
    maxlength: [50, 'max length'],
  },
});
```

```
app.post('/api/v1/customers', async (req, res, next) => {
  const customers = req.body;
  //validate array
  const validationPromises = customers.map(customer => {
    const newCustomer = new Customer(customer);
    return newCustomer.validate();
  });

  try {
    await Promise.all(validationPromises);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new Error(`validation failed: ${error.message}`, 400));
  }
  const newCustomers = await Customer.insertMany(customers);

  if (!newCustomers) {
    return next(new Error('insert failed', 500));
  }

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      newCustomers
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Wonderful yet simple solution!